# Multi Party Protocol - Proof with semi-honest adversaries

Tags: protocols

I have designed a protocol where one entity acts as a "client", sends information to one of many "server-parties". This second party sends some other information to another "server-party" and so on, until the last "server-party" engages in an oblivious transfer with the "client".

Is it ok to consider the three two-party cases (client-first, "server-party", "server-party i", "server-party j", and last "server-party", client) or do I need multi-party-proof techniques in order to prove that the protocol is secure against semi-honest adversaries?

Could you please recommend me some related papers?

Comment: This seems almost entirely related to Cryptographic theory. There's a Cryptography Stack Exchange. I suggest this question he migrated there. I don't have enough points to migrate it myself.